# Constraint gives a warning on ranges are not relevant

Tags: specman

the following code creates a warning on DEPR_NEG_OR_LARGE_SELECT_WEIGHT:

```
keep soft MyVar == select {
 0xffffffffff: 0;
 10: [1..10];
 10: [11..20];
};
keep MyVar != 0;
```

i would expect the check to consider only the relevant ranges...

Answer (score 0):

0xffffffffff is not a legal syntax of a select weight. Only values between 0 and MAX_INT are valid.

The tool simply protects you from illegal expressions. Just as you get a load/compile time error if you write any other illegal code. It doesn't try to understand the deeper meaning, or whether the code is at all called.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough for your needs.

```
keep soft MyVar == select {

  1: [1..10];

  1: [11..20];

};

keep MyVar != 0;

keep soft MyVar in [1..20]; // This is also enough in place of weighted random constraint.
```